# (iOS) don't move up a modal view when the keyboard appears

Tags: ios, keyboard, popover, modal-view

I have a modal view (form sheet style) and i don't want it to move up when the keyboard appears because i have a popover inside that doesn't follow the modal view and looks really bad.

Basically i want to prevent moving up the modal view when the keyboard shows up

thanks!!

Here the images that show how it looks

[image]

[image]

EDIT - SOLUTION

Thanks for helping me!!

what i did at the end was to change the style to UIModalPresentationPageSheet and change the superview bounds to look like a form sheet.

```
self.checkIn = [[ApparatusCheckInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ApparatusCheckInViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.checkIn setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];
[self presentViewController:self.checkIn animated:YES completion:nil];
CGRect bounds = self.checkIn.view.superview.bounds;
bounds.size.height *= 0.8;
bounds.size.width *= 0.6;
self.checkIn.view.superview.bounds = bounds;
```

Comment: You need to set your VC to page sheet instead of form sheet.

Comment: I don't want to change the view style to UIModalPresentationPageSheet.
Is there another solution?

Comment: thanks to @Doc and CaptJack, finally i changed the style and resized the view to look like a form sheet.